# javascript alert dosent work with php condition

Tags: javascript, php

Created One form which is giving alert on submit button with three condition

1) Payment method is Bank and amount is greghter than 900000

2) Payment method is Cash and amount is greghter than 20000

I have amount which is convert number with comma and decimal point (.)

My problem is condition dosent shows alert with condition.
And if throws alert box than only for first condition while i was checking second condition.

help me to solve this problem.

here is my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['Reset']))
{
$re_id=$_POST['rec_id'];
$re_no=$_POST['rec_no'];
//$re_date=$_POST['rec_date'];
$re_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST['rec_date']));
$re_acc=$_POST['rec_acc'];
$re_pay=$_POST['rec_pay'];
//$re_amount=$_POST['rec_amount'];
$re_amount = number_format($_POST['rec_amount'], 2, '.', ',');

$query="UPDATE tbl_reciept SET rec_no='$re_no', rec_date='$re_date', rec_acc='$re_acc', rec_pay_type='$re_pay', rec_amount='$re_amount' WHERE rec_id='$re_id'";


if($re_pay=="Cash" && $re_amount>=20000)  
    {  
    mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
    echo "<script>
alert('amount is grater than 20000');
window.location.href='../reciept.php';
</script>";

    }  
    else if($re_pay=="Bank" && $re_amount>= 900000)  
    {  
    mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
    echo "<script>
alert('amount is grater than 900000');
window.location.href='../reciept.php';
</script>";
    } 
    else 
    {
    mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);
    header('Location: ../reciept.php');
    }

}
```

Comment: `$re_pay="Cash"` should be `$re_pay=="Cash"` - not sure that's you're problem though, but it's a problem

Comment: first condition works but second one dosent work

Comment: because the first condition sets $re_pay to Cash - `==` tests for equality, `=` assigns a value

Answer (score 0):

```
This will work...
echo "<script>
alert('amount is grater than 900000');
window.location.href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions';
</script>";
Note: Pass full path other wise case Bellow case

    window.location.protocol = "http:"
    window.location.host = "www.test.com"
    window.location.pathname = "example/index.html"
```